# Is it possible to make an endless CSS-grid to create a gallery

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, css-grid

Dear fellow developers,

I want to create a portfolo website with an gallery, similar to the one found on instagram with 3 pictures in a row. I tried to utilize css-grid for that. The grid's looking like this: (Please note that the 225px column/row is a white boundary, similar to a passepartout)

```
grid-template-columns: 225px repeat(3, 1fr) 225px;
grid-template-rows: 225px auto;
```

above the gallery there are two header elements:

```
#header-l{grid-row: 1 / 1; grid-column: 2 / 2;}
```

and

```
#header-r{grid-row: 1 / 1; grid-column: 3 / span 2;}
```

That's the state I currently got. However, in order for the gallery to show up, in need to assign a height to the grid-container. I used

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

however, when I add items to a third row of the gallery the cells do not keep their height but go half as high.

========

**What I want to achieve is a system where I can add an unlimeted amount of images in rows of three, that all have the aspect ratio 1:1.**

The full code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/timlwsk/xqfat628/1/

*EDIT: Typo*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's multiple ways to reach your goal. First of all i've tested your code. Would be cool if you could update the images with some random Unsplash images because you can't see any local images on jsfiddle. However if you add the grids 3/2/3/2, 3/3/3/3,... even with 4 it seems to work fine on the fiddle. But let me give you some alternatives.

Solution 1:
-> Create rows, that way your grid can start at 1/2/1/2 anytime you create a new row. In your case, your grid is defined in a container so you would want to duplicate that container for every single row (medium nice)

Solution 2: 
-> You can create a div within your grid that takes the dimensions 2-4 and inside this div, you can create another div (img-wrapper) which is width: calc(100%/3) and make it an inline-block (also add some margin to top and bottom). This way you can create as many image objects as you want and you can even adjust it pretty easy for mobile. Just like @media screen and (max-width:500px) img-wrapper{ width: 100%}. This might be the best solution for you

Solution 3: 
-> Go for a library such as bootstrap, you can actually adjust anything you want in the variables.scss file

Comment: Hey! Thank you a man, I got it working now! However: I get a white boundary between each img-wrapper, with margin and podding set to none. Due to this only 2 pics fit in a row. Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/timlwsk/a8tb5c3r/ (FYI: images are from my google drive)

Comment: Post script: I needed to set the font-size: 0, so that there is no gap between the divs. Now it's working like a charm!

Comment: @timlwsk, Nice looks good. I've seen th gaps, good job figuring out that this was caused by font size. Why ever it was a fontsize issue :D

Comment: As far as I understand it's caused by the new line after a div. This "Return-key" has a font-size apparently.